# d3 force layout nodes are pinning on dblick but appearance does not modify

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Using and playing around with the Les Miserables Json data, I coded from modifications in d3.   I was able to code everything except highlighting/marking a node if it is in the "fixed" state (vs the force graph layout).  When you double click a node, it will freeze, a drag and move will pin it somewhere while all the other nodes (by default) in the force layout.  When you double click the node again, the node is unpinned, and floating in the force layout as usual.  The second thing I wanted to do is that if the node is in a “pinned” state, the node should be a different color, or highlighted somehow.  I tried a few ways within the method chaining, checking with conditional statements for the node state to modify the node features, but they are not working.  I also separated out the dblclick handler as an outside function (which is my current version.

I put my code here of the original attempt within the method chains:
http://pastebin.com/SqrqgVET

I also tried another way, using a variable “pinned” to determine the state of the node, within the double-click, to modify the nodes border, and change the state accordingly but that is not changing the node’s appearance either. There is a console.log() statement, and the function is going into the if else portions accordingly.

http://pastebin.com/dzEw42mQ

Below is the current version.

Any feedback would be great.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.node {
  cursor: move;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node.fixed {
    fill: #f00;
}

   .link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>

<head>
<title>Victor Hugo Had No Internet</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Size of region to render on
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([1, 10])
    .range(colorbrewer.BrBG[9]);

//D3 force directed layout
//Try playing with the charge and link distance
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-100)
    .linkDistance(40)
    //.on("tick", tick) //event ADDED
    .size([width, height]);

//Add our canvas
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);



//Select the miserables data ;)
d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

//Add the links
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

//Add the nodes
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d){ return Math.sqrt(d.coolness);})
      .attr("stroke", "#ffffff")
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(force.drag)
        .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.group);}); //});
        //.style("border", 5);//function(d) {
             //if (d.fixed==false) {return 4}; });





// node.append("text") //label
 //       .attr("dx", 6)
 //       .attr("dy", ".10em")
 //       .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

 //add labels
  var labels = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr({"x":function(d){return d.x;},
              "y":function(d){return d.y;}})
        .text(function(d) {
              if (d.coolness>25 && d.name.length > 6) {return d.name.substring(0,6)+'...'}
              if (d.coolness>25 && d.name.length < 6) {return d.name}
              else    { return null } ;})
        .call(force.drag);

//Update stuff for animation:
//   This takes the physics simulation for the force directed graph and
//   sets the location of the nodes and edges to the new positions
  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    labels.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })        
           .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

  });

    // action to take on mouse double click

function dblclick(d) {  //color, stroke not working.
        //var pinned  = d3.select(this).attr("stroke");
        console.log("dblclick")
        if (d.fixed == true) { //pinned state
        console.log("pinned")
        d3.select(this)
        .attr("stroke", "#ffffff")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);//now unpin
        } else { //else not pinned state
        console.log("not pinned")
        d3.select(this)
        .attr("stroke", "#000000")
        .attr("stroke-width", 4)
        .classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
        }


        }//end dbl click

});

</script>`
```

Here is the output of the console log (where I added console.log(this) to check the right element is being passed to the dblclick function and if parameters are being set accordingly:

```
[Log] dblclick (miserables_graph.html, line 131)
[Log] <circle class=​"node fixed" r=​"9.1104335791443" stroke=​"#000000" style=​"fill:​ #f6e8c3;​" cx=​"630.38114584665" cy=​"98.39845698676822" stroke-width=​"4">​</circle>​ (miserables_graph.html, line 132)

[Log] not pinned (miserables_graph.html, line 140)
[Log] dblclick (miserables_graph.html, line 131)
[Log] <circle class=​"node" r=​"9.1104335791443" stroke=​"#ffffff" style=​"fill:​ #f6e8c3;​" cx=​"630.38114584665" cy=​"98.39845698676822" stroke-width=​"1.5">​</circle>​ (miserables_graph.html, line 132)

[Log] pinned (miserables_graph.html, line 134)
```

Comment: Did you verify whether the double click event is being received and the class is being set?

Comment: I know that the function, dblclick, is happening (as a separate function or part of the chain of methods) because of the console.log("dblclick") ("not pinned") being printed.  I assume d.fixed=false & d.fixed=true is happened, because the nodes are responding accordingly to a user double click.  As for d3.select(this) - I added console.log(this), and the print outs show the right node is being selected.. I edited my OP to show this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff After much debugging, I determined that I could have other node attributes change for the pinned state, such as radius, fill color, even having dashed lines `.attr('stroke-dasharray' ...` around a node, but the stroke color `(.attr("stroke", "green"))` and width `.attr("stroke-width", 10)` will not visually change and wants to stay in default (no changes) whether pinned or not.  (though in the console.log print outs, the parameters do show a change in the stroke width and color as pasted at the bottom of my OP).  I am still curious why this is so for the stroke width/color?

Comment: Ah, try `.style(...)` instead of `.attr(...)`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that worked! Thanks.  For my own learning, what is a general rule to know when to use .style vs .attr?  I ask as I have seen both used in code examples while searching.

Comment: `.style()` should be used for CSS styles. SVG is not particularly picky about this and usually both will work, but in cases like yours where you're trying to override an existing style value, it breaks.